# Module '"react-router-dom"' has no exported member 'useSearchParams'

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to make sure to redirect a user to a url by using useSearchParams, but it's not letting me  import it!

I'm getting this error: (Module '"react-router-dom"' has no exported member 'useSearchParams').ts(2305), when I try to import it:

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` do you have?

Answer (score 1):

`useSearchParams` is a RRDv6 hook. Ensure you've correctly installed `react-router-dom@6` as a dependency in your project. From the root project directory run the following command to install the latest RRDv6 version and update/save your package.json file.

```
npm install --save react-router-dom@6
```